# Identity Server: redirect after logout with WS Federation

Tags: identityserver3, ws-federation

I try to redirect user after logout from Identity Server to my client app.
I use next code  for identity server setup:

```
 RelyingParties = (from RelyingPartyElement element in section.RelyingParties
                          select new RelyingParty()
                          {
                              PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string>()
                              {
                                "http://localhost:xxx"  
                              },
```

Also,  signOutReply param has been set to "http://localhost:xxx/"  for ws federation section.
But it is not enough for redirect user after sign out.
What i need to do for achive goals, described above?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this? You would need to add Owin Extensions and point to signout

https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/federated-signout.html

Comment: Welcome to SO. Link as answers are best for comments not answers. I suggest editing the above answer (and format it) to add the main parts so its in one place.